# jQuery get accumulative height of images and adjust their heights based on pixel offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, bar-chart

I need to build an html based stacking bar chart for weasy print pdf. I have done so by assigning fractional percentages to color block images. Third-party libs are not an option. This works great for all browsers I must support aside from Safari as they round fractional percentages. Because the data is accurate, and this is just a little eye candy... I just want to "jury rig" it.

1. I know my barchart height is always 600px
2. I need the total height of all my images combined (lets say it's 595px)
3. Because this is in percentages I can't just get a wrapper `height()`
4. After getting the height remainder, I would like to then iterate through each of the images set their height to `height()` + 1px until we reach 600px total. In my example case that would mean iterating through 5 images adding 1px to each.

**GOOD Bar-Chart** VS.  **Safari Bar-Chart**

[image: This is an example of my working barchart]
[image]

**EXAMPLE HTML:**

```
<div class="bar-container">
    <div class="inner-barstack">
        <img src="my/color-square" style="height:41.5%" alt="Bifid... 41.5%">
        <img src="my/color-square" style="height:39.32%" alt="Clost... 39.32%">
        <img src="my/color-square" style="height:0.68%" alt="Corio... 0.68%>
        <img src="my/color-square" style="height:0.5%" alt="Veill... 0.5%">
        <img src="my/color-square" style="height:0.5%" alt="Enter... 0.5%">
        <img src="my/color-square" style="height:0.5%" alt="Bacte... 0.5%">
        <img src="my/color-square" style="height:17%" alt="Lacto... 17%">
    </div>
</div>
```

EXAMPLE CSS:

```
.bar-container {
    height: 600px;
    width: 80px;
}
.inner-barstack {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.inner-barstack img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: So... what/where is the problem?

Comment: that's impressive, but what do you have against canvas?

Comment: How does this look now? Because if the height of all of them adds up to 100%, and the container is 600px tall, the height of all of them should always come out to 600px too. So what's going on exactly?

Comment: @Dekel - the problem is that Safari will actually round the percentages so I don't get a true 100% fill in my 600px tall bar. It leaves anywhere from 10 - 20 pixes off at the bottom of the bar depending on how many items are stacked. This is only a Safari issue. So I was hoping to just cheat it by adding a pixel to each img item until I reach the 600px height. I'll add a safari version so you folks can see the bug

Comment: @Adrianopolis - That makes no sense. If it's generated on the server why are you showing us HTML? canvas IS html. IF you can use HTML, you can use canvas.

Comment: and if it really is generated on the server it will proabably be easier to genrate the graph with php or whatever you've got on the back

Comment: It's all python and jinja.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce this doesn't meet our requirements from eng. I was given a task to work this in HTML and canvas does not meet our browser compatibility requirements. Canvas is not acceptable for this project.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to explicitly define your heights, you can store the percentages in a data attribute and assign the heights directly.

```
<img src="my/color-square" data-pct="41.5" alt="Bifid... 41.5%">

<script>
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-pct]')
var len = imgs.length
var i = -1
var t, pct

while(++i < len){
   t = imgs[len]
   pct = parseFloat(t.getAttribute('data-pct'))/100
   t.style.height = [pct * 600, 'px'].join("")
}
</script>
```